# Python BUG or I don't get how encoding works? len, find, and re.search do nothing with no empty, successful subprocess.communicate() execution result

Tags: python, find, popen

For a reason I cannot understand I cannot do nothing with the output of Popen.communicate, except for print it to terminal.

If I save the output to a variable, the variable contains the text, because I can print it to terminal too, but len returns 0, re.search match nothing, and find always returns -1.

The offending function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os
import sys
import getopt
import subprocess
import os.path
import re

def get_video_duration (ifile):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ffprobe", ifile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    info_str = p.communicate()[0].decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
    print(info_str) # for debug, the information about the file prints ok
    duration_start = info_str.find("Duration")
    # duration_start = "AJDKLAJSL Duration:".find("Duration"), this test was ok
    duration_end = info_str.find("start", duration_start)
    number_start = info_str.find(" ", duration_start, duration_end) + 1
    number_end = info_str.find(",", number_start, duration_end)

    temp = info_str[number_start:number_end].split(":")

    return int(temp[0]) * 60 * 60 + int(temp[1]) * 60 + int(temp[2])
```

I attempted different variations. Like do not use .decode(), change find for a single re.search, implement my own find by iterating each character (the problem is that I need len for this, and len always returns 0 for that particular string/byte_array).

It is a bug of some sort or I am doing something wrong about the string encoding. I cannot figure what exactly is the problem. Any help appreciated.

Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits
Python 2.7

Comment: Please show an example of code, including data, that displays the behavior you describe.  That is, print the data, print the return value of `find`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong with encoding. Your problem is that ffprobe sends its output (including the duration info you're looking for) to stderr, not stdout. Do this and you should be fine:

```
def get_video_duration (ifile):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ffprobe", ifile], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    info_str = p.communicate()[1].decode(sys.stderr.encoding)
```

The reason your print() call *seems* to be working is that it's printing nothing (because info_str truly is empty)... but the stderr output is being dumped to the console, which gives you the illusion that what you're seeing is the result of your print() call.